# showing error in package explorer

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working in android in eclipse . I am new to this platform. When I create a new android project I find error in package explorer without doing anything. Can anyone help me??

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the project using projet>clean in eclipse menu. OR chcek whether you have set correct path of android sdk in eclipse preferences..

If you are still having same problem then provide some more details on it.

Comment: I only create the project. I also check the path of sdk . In package explorer view the cross sign only in the created package not in the src folder or res or manifest xml . When I try to run the project error massage come that there are some errors but what type of error is not specified in message.

Answer (score 0):

The error will be visible within the project tree. Each file that has an error will be marked as such. Try what @mudit said, clean your project and it will likely rebuild automatically and clean up. If not you have a project configuration error with library paths, classpaths, etc..